# How to force a garbage collector swep on libgdx?

Tags: libgdx, memory-efficiency

I found that you can control your memory usage on libgdx with:

```
int javaHeap = Gdx.app.getJavaHeap();
int nativeHeap = Gdx.app.getNativeHeap();
```

But, How can I force a garbage collector cleanup? I want to force in special moments, like screen change on a game.

Comment: My issues is same as you, @Zhen, but not on getJavaHeap nor getNativeHeap(). When I'm performing several screen changes, I tested on the desktop and it worked countlessly but not in device, which ends up at 6th or 7th screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java's garbage collector is nondeterministic. There's `System.gc();` but it will likely do nothing. See [the StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481178/forcing-garbage-collection-in-java) for further discussion.

Comment: I have a question, @Anko. Is it a bad practice to call or declare a forced garbage collector according to your answer?

Comment: @David There's a [SO question about that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414105/why-is-it-a-bad-practice-to-call-system-gc) too. A summary of the answers: It *is* bad practice. `System.gc();` is not defined to do any particular thing. Depending on many unknown factors, it may do one of many even potentially harmful things.

Comment: Then that means I have to make the program nice and simple, right?

Comment: @David You always should! :)

Comment: There is another question regarding your answer, @Anko. Is it won't matter even if I manage the memory using a simple Java's **getters** and **setters**, virtual memory will still depleting or there is an exception when using a `static` keyword?

Comment: @David Maybe! Who knows. Memory is managed by the Java virtual machine. Once you give it a value, the way that value is stored/collected is internally implementation-defined (it could be anything). The only sure interface is when giving variables values and retrieving them. Java provides no guarantees about what happens in between and it may even change between versions of a VM. So to answer you: That might be true in some cases (I don't know), but certainly don't rely on it *staying* true.

Comment: @David I coincidentally found [this article](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/general-programming/modern-garbage-collectors-under-the-hood-r2995) just now, which is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: what's with the _Eden Space_ thing? When this space is full, it means that the program automatically closed when `memoryOutOfBoundsException` occured unless it was moved first to the one of the _Survival Space_ slots so that the program resumes? I wonder.

Answer (score 2):

Many of the libgdx classes have memory allocated across JNI. Destroying/disposing of classes should handle this for you. Forcing a GC call may not be de-allocating classes if they reside in native managed memory. Last time I used libgdx, it provided decent logs of when memory was allocated/destroyed. Do yo have a specific issue when loading new screens?

**Update**:
Based on this [page](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/ScreenAndGameClasses), there's a screen.dispose() and comments suggesting that you should reuse your screen class to avoid GC.

Answer (score 2):

While you can give a hint to the runtime engine via System.gc() this is a "hint" and not a command so you cannot rely on it to actually trigger garbage collection. Even if it were a command, forcing garbage collection is unlikely to accomplish what you want- the garbage collection process itself consumes resources so when it runs your game will be impacted. So, in fact, you want to avoid garbage collection to ensure your game isn't contending with the GC process for resources, see this link for a libgdx specific discussion: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/ForceGarbageCollection

Instead of dynamically allocating many short lived objects that require garbage collection I think the better strategy would be to allocate long life objects at times the user isn't playing, e.g. loading screen or first start up.  These objects can even be returned to a pool when no longer needed and then reused as necessary.